# Is Prime Bounded Quadratic Congruence NP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np-complete

**Bounded Quadratic Congruence:**

Instance: Three positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Question: Is there a positive integer $x<c$ such that $x^{2} \equiv a \, (mod \ b)$?

Bounded Quadratic Congruence is $NP$-$complete$ [1].

**Prime Bounded Quadratic Congruence:**

Instance: Three positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $b$ is a prime number.

Question: Is there a positive integer $x<c$ such that $x^{2} \equiv a \, (mod \ b)$?

Is this problem $NP$-$complete$ as well?

**Reference:**

[1] Kenneth L. Manders and Leonard M. Adleman, NP-complete decision problems for binary quadratics, Journal of Computer and System Sciences 16 (1978), no. 2, pp. 168–184.

Comment: The inputs $a$, $b$, and $c$ are given in binary right?  :)

Comment: Yes, they are given in binary encoding...

Comment: Michael Wehar, I think this problem could be solved in randomized polynomial time. Look at this:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Comment: Therefore, Prime Bounded Quadratic Congruence will be in NP-complete if and only if RP=NP. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link!!  Well I don't know how your randomized polynomial time algorithm works.  But, I think this is a neat approach and idea.  :)

Comment: Yes, the problem is solvable in randomized polynomial time. So if you know this, what is the point of the question?

Comment: Emil Jeřábek, there is something wrong here!!! If we find a solution for a prime, then we can find a solution for the power of this prime using the Hensel's lemma:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma. And if you can find the solution for a prime power then you can find the solution to the Bounded Quadratic Congruence problem using the Chinese remainder theorem:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem. What do you think?

Comment: The number of solutions of $x^2\equiv a\pmod b$ is exponential in the number of distinct prime factors of $b$, and there is no shortcut how to check if some of them is below $c$ other than by generating all of them. So this only gives you an exponential-time algorithm. And of course, you need first to have the prime factorization of $b$, which is itself not a light assumption. (This is, however, not actually important, as Manders and Adleman also show NP-completeness of the problem when the full factorization of $b$ is given as input.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved in randomized polynomial time. Look at this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Therefore, if Prime Bounded Quadratic Congruence would be in NP-complete, then RP = NP.

Consequently, the answer of this question is an outstanding problem in complexity theory, so it is not worth to ask it here...